# d3.event returns an error

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

[Plunk here](http://plnkr.co/edit/KyJXXbpZjB6Gp4pAOEcN?p=preview)

On the " first " page, there is a circle and its label
the label should be draggable while the page is on its own
The problem arises when I put the page in this angular framework, it is return the following:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of null

is there anything I am missing?
I am new to angular and d3, please help thanks.

Here is the relevant code for the drag function:

```
 function dragged(d) {
    var x = d3.event.x,
          y = d3.event.y,
          textID = this.id,
          lineID = 'line' + textID.slice(4,textID.length);
          console.log(d3.event);
  d3.select(this)
    .attr("x", x)
    .attr("y", y);

  d3.select("#"+ lineID)
    .attr("x2", x)
    .attr("y2", y);
  }
```

Comment: Look at this [answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/bwdNirt2uEU) by Jake Vanderplas. You are having the same issue. Just remove the reference to d3 in first.html,`<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`, and it works.

Comment: thanks! Such a simple fix yet I spent so long looking at the code...

Answer (score -1):

Delete the d3 reference in the individual html as suggested by FernOfTheAndes